# dynamic dns networking, subdomain ddns1.ex.com redirected to www.ex.com

Tags: networking, ddns

I've created 3 ddns from my google domains, let says

- www.chanindo.com
- ts.chanindo.com
- tonny.chanindo.com

`tonny.chanindo.com` links has been establised OK (to `digitalocean.com`) with google API, and can be accessed when I browse `tonny.chanindo.com`.

I then updated the ddns data of `ts.chanindo.com` (link to my home computer) with google API too. The updated data reflected to `google domains panel`. Google support guys too said it point correctly to `ts.chanindo.com`. So it should be accessible when I type `ts.chanindo.com` from my browser.

Alas, when I browse `ts.chanindo.com`, it return **'The site can't be reached'**. But It can be browsed from `www.chanindo.com`. Why? What went wrong?

Why the digitalocean one (`tonny.chanindo.com`) can be accessed OK but the one from my computer (`ts.chanindo.com`) cannot be reached, but strangely it accessible from `www.chanindo.com`?

Comment: ex.com is not your domain name, and is not delegated. If you want help, please provide the appropriate domain name so we can do tests on it.

Comment: @davidgo: noted. I've change it reflected to my real subdomain. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:  Log into your router and portmap port 80 to the Internal IP address of your web server.

Longer explanation:

With the updated information, it would appear that DNS is resolving fine (save for www.chanindo.com - but that would seem irrelevant to your problem).

The probable cause of your problem is NAT.   Most home computers are behind a router which shares a single IP address, and mapping internal IP addresses to this address.   Because of this 1:many relationship, it is necessary to use Port Forwarding (Pin Holing), or a DMZ so the router can know which PC to forward requests targetted at your static IP to.

Another possibility - if you have already done this forwarding - your ISP may be using Carrier Grade NAT, in which case the external IP address you are using is shared by multiple ISP subscribers - in which case you can't do much other then get a new ISP issued to you which is not a CGN one.

Comment: Spot on! Thanks! I think I've set the port forwarding and the DMZ correctly pointing to my internal IP. I recheck my internal IP. Turn out it point to my wifi IP while I'm using my LAN to connect to Internet.